# Maria db remote access

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to remote access maria db on google compute engine. After comment below line `#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1`

and restart maria db, it still binds to 127.0.0.1:3306.
 The file that I edited is 
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

May anyone help me to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind it to 0.0.0.0 to access it remotely. Uncomment the `bind-address` field and change the value to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but it still bind to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You need to restart MariaDB as well for the new settings to take effect

Comment: Also, your firewall might be stopping it. Check that port 3306 is open.

Comment: Also, check the user account you are using can access it remotely. user@localhost and user@otherserver.com are two different users.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally I shutdown DB with command 'mysqladmin' and then restart it. It's solved.