# How to make connection to Maria DB Docker image - using MYSQL Workbench or sql developer

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to use MariaDB container

docker run -p 3306:3306 -p 33060:33060 --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Blah....3 -d mariadb/server:10.4

the question -
[Maria db remote access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040999/maria-db-remote-access)

is not working

The my.cnf has bind address commented, so uncommented and used 0.0.0.0

```
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

[mysqldump]
```

I would like to connect to the db using any UI - SQL developer, MYSQL workbench or any

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message says if failing to connect as user `pyapp`.

If your `mysql.user` there pyapp host is 172.17.0.3.

The host is the origin IP, the IP that is running MySQL Workbench.

If you aren't running the MySQL Workbench on the same machine as the container, then change the the `pymapp@xxx` user.

If it is the same host, investigation any access control around the 172.17.x.x network.

Comment: I ran the command - docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mariadbtest   and  tried username = root@170.17.0.2  . Cannot fetch list of available databases: 
Cannot connect to server on host '170.17.0.2': Connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use 127.0.0.1 or localhost. Its crazy, why I cant use the docker container given IP - 172.17.0.1

SQL Developer

[image]

[image]

Client connections show IP - 172.17.0.1

[image]